# Jquery Knob not working in IE 8

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-knob

Iam using jquery knob in my website. it works fine in mozilla ,crome and safari. but not working in ie8. This is my ie result :(. [image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".dial").knob({
    readOnly: true,
    fgColor: "#00ABC6",
    bgColor: "#666666",
    thickness: 0.25,
    width:50,
    height:50,
                });
});
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Knob uses canvas and Internet explorer 8 does not support the canvas element.
http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas.

**EDIT:** 
You could try adding a polyfill for IE8, https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#canvas . But I don't know if any of them is compatible with jQuery knob.

**EDIT 2:** 
http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/ might do the tric, [Jquery Knob not working in IE 8.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743161/jquery-knob-not-working-in-ie-8)